# ClassClassException when including dependency in pom

Tags: jboss, maven-3, camunda

I use JBoss to develop applications.

I create a new module `CAMUNDA_HOME\server\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules\org\camunda\bpm\identity\camunda-identity-dbldap\main`

The folder include 2 files:
camunda-identity-dbldap-7.2.0.jar & module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.camunda.bpm.identity.camunda-identity-dbldap">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="camunda-identity-dbldap-7.2.0.jar" />
  </resources>

  <dependencies>

    <module name="sun.jdk" />

    <module name="javax.api" />
    <module name="org.camunda.bpm.camunda-engine" />
    <module name="org.camunda.bpm.identity.camunda-identity-ldap" />

  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I included "camunda-identity-dbldap" in pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.identity</groupId>
        <artifactId>camunda-identity-dbldap</artifactId>
        <version>${camunda-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

DbAndLdapIdentityProviderFactory  exists in "camunda-identity-dbldap.jar" and also be loaded in pom.

I tried to cast the class in my project.

```
    ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl processEngineConfiguration = (ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl)ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine().getProcessEngineConfiguration();
    DbAndLdapIdentityProviderFactory factory = (DbAndLdapIdentityProviderFactory)processEngineConfiguration.getIdentityProviderSessionFactory();
    LdapConfiguration configuration = factory.getLdapConfiguration();
```

Unfortunately, it reports ClassCastException, it cannot cast DbAndLdapIdentityProviderFactory into DbAndLdapIdentityProviderFactory. It seems that two classes were loaded in different class loader. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You probably get the CCE because you have added the library inside JBoss and your own project.
The engine uses the version from JBoss and you try to cast it inside your project using the library in your project.

The solution is to add the library used by JBoss to your project by declaring it as a dependency in your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (org.camunda.bpm.identity.camunda-identity-dbldap) so JBoss will load it for you. You have to set the library in your pom.xml at scope 'provided' then.

Comment: My project doesn't have "MANIFEST.MF" but it has "jboss-deployment-structure.xml". Is it OK?